# where to find schema.xml file for solr 5

Tags: xml, solr, schema, solr5

Where to find schema.xml file for solr 5,
or it's should be created manually,
Should I create schema.xml for each core or schema.xml for each example?

Comment: are you running in cloud mode or standalone mode?

Comment: I'm running in cloud mode,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cloud mode, you'll have a schema per collection. This schema will not be added automatically. You need not create the file yourself from scratch. You can find a ready to use configset in the `example` directory that you can then modify for your own use.

In cloud mode, all your config files are stored on the zookeeper. You can connect to it using the `zkcli.sh` script provided with the solr installation. For 6.x you can find it under `${SOLR_HOME}/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh`

To upload a schema set:

`server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -z localhost:9983 -cmd upconfig -confdir example/files/conf -confname collection1`

Create a new collection and then to retrieve files:

`server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:9983 -cmd get /configs/<your_collection_name>/managed-schema`